# populate the value selected from the popup jsp to current jsp

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jsf-2

I'm using the following code to generate a popup

### Current Page

```
        <script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
        function popUp(URL) {
            day = new Date();
            id = day.getTime();
            eval("page" + id + " = window.open(URL, '" + id + "', 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=1,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=1,width=250,height=800 left = 630,top = 502');");
        }
    </script>
<h:outputText value="Student Number : "></h:outputText>
<h:inputText id="stuNo" value="#{stuBean.stuNumber}" onfocus="javascript:popUp('OpenStudentList.jsp')" > </h:inputText>
```

### Popup.jsp

```
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
        function setValue(stuNo){
            window.opener.document.getElementById(stuNo).value;
            window.close();
        }
    </script>
<h:dataTable id="dt" value="#{Student.openStuList}" var="openStuList"  >
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText style=""value="Student Number" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:form>
                    <h:commandLink style="" value="#{openStuList.stuNumber}" onclick="javascript:setValue(#{openStuList.stuNumber})" ></h:commandLink></h:form>
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
```

my popup jsp has a datable which contains a field student Number each of which is a link. When i click on the link..I want the value to be populated in the current jsp's textbox. I've tried using the setValue() javascript function which didn't work
Need suggestions on this

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea. Add an ID on the current page's `input` with something like `id="student_number` and then on the link in your pop-up have it refer to the opener window to update the textbox, something like:

`yourWindowObject.opener.document.getElementById('student_number').value = 'some value';`

To do this you probably need to find a way to reference the created pop-up object and get its opener. Seems you are creating the variable that holds the pop-up using eval with current time which may be hard to refer to it easily.

Comment: to reference to the `window.opener` you need to use the variable that you used for `window.open` e.g. `var win = window.open(...)` the window created will be referenced by `win` variable. if you use that you can refer to the opener window by using `win.opener` then using the sample above to access the `input` box that you want to change.